# SQL Count avabiles rooms betwen interval

Tags: sql

I'm working on a hotel booking module, and after a few days I'm stack.

```
Tables
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

rooms             bookings
========          =============
room_id           b_id
avabile_rooms     b_room_id
                  check_in
                  check_out
                  b_rooms
```

== Where ==
avabile_rooms - the number of rooms avabile
b_rooms = the number of rooms with this b_id booked

```
Values needed
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
room_id and number_of_rooms_avabile foreach avabile room in interval A(check_in) - B(check_out) 

Current Query
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
SELECT r.* FROM rooms AS r WHERE r.room_id NOT IN
(
  SELECT b.b_room_id FROM bookings AS b
  WHERE (b.check_out >= ? AND b.check_in <= ?)
  OR (b.check_out <= ? AND b.check_in >= ?)
)
```

Now I get the avabile rooms without taking into account the avabile_rooms/b_rooms

```
The Unkown Query (I thik It needs to be something like this)
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
SELECT r.* FROM rooms AS r WHERE r.room_id IS IN
(
  SELECT b.b_room_id FROM bookings AS b
  OR b.b_id IS NULL 
  OR (b.check_out >= ? AND b.check_in <= ?)
  OR (b.check_out <= ? AND b.check_in >= ?)
)
```

I'm not figured out how to get the room_id/number_of_rooms_avabile 
P.S.: I did a deep search but did not find a solution that takes into account the number of rooms.
Thanks.

Comment: I have one question on the design of the table ROOM. It has two columns - ROOM_ID, which makes sense, and then the second column is AVAILABLE_ROOMS. What purpose does it serve? As far as a RROM_ID denotes ONE room and not more than one rooms, there is no sense of having the other column in that table, especially to store "the numebr of rooms available". Am I missing something here?

Comment: do you need available rooms for today only(fixed date) or date range?

Comment: @MilenPavlov: for date range that will be selected

Comment: @Incognito: You are right, there is little mess up I just saw that to. Practically the table rooms should be called room_types this would more clear. This is because in a hotel ,ay be more rooms of one type. Probabily it should be better to add a separate table room_types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
select  rt.room_type_id, available = rt.available_rooms - isnull(sum(b.b_rooms), 0)
from    room_types rt
left join bookings b 
    on rt.room_type_id = b.b_room_type_id
    and b.check_in <= @end_date
    and b.check_out >= @start_date
group by rt.room_type_id, rt.available_rooms
```

I renamed your rooms table to room_types as discussed in the comments, and renamed columns as appropriate.

This will take the number of available rooms and subtract all bookings that have any overlap with the selected date range, which I believe is what you want.

Depending on your business rules, you may want this instead:

```
where   b.check_in < @end_date
and     b.check_out > @start_date
```

Comment: The only problem is with available_rooms that are not in booking table, so I added to the condition OR IS NULL, but now I obtain available_rooms = Null for no booked rooms. Is there a way to change this value to 0 from sql query? Thanks!

Comment: You are correct. I have edited the answer to handle room_types with no bookings.